# Selenium IDE Not Typing Entry

Tags: selenium-ide

I am a beginner with Selenium, and I am trying a simple case of going to Wikipedia, entering some text (e.g - James Joyce), and asserting that James Joyce is on the page after clicking the "go" button. However, Selenium is not registering that I am entering "James Joyce". When I stop recording and view the commands, all I see is that Selenium goes to the correct page, but clicks on the button without typing the data. Is there a way to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is a problem with Wikipedia. Not sure why it doesn;t work. You can enter the command manually. For Selenium IDE that is Command: type, Target: searchInput, Value: James Joyce.

Comment: Yeah, I got that to work by manually doing it, but I am still unsure why its doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't always record an action. It depend on how the page is built.
You will have to Manual create some inputs.

One work around I have is to manually enter the data, then highlight it and right-click.
You should now have a option that will give you the target field. Click on it
and manually change the command.